# What is the most commonly accepted synonym or synonymous phrase in linguistics for "wh-question"?

Tags: syntax, terminology, questions

The term "wh-question" seems transparent enough for English speakers, but reeks of English language chauvinism.   I have heard such questions referred to as "information questions,"  "content questions, and "question-word questions," but I don't know what synonym or synonymous phrase for "wh-question" is most commonly used among professional linguists these days. I haven't been able to find an answer to my question.

Since my hobby is writing reference grammars for imaginary languages, an answer to this question will be useful for me.

Comment: When I was (until 10 years ago) a lecturer at a university English department, "wh-question" was the common term; but that was in Britain, and an English department, so no qualms about chauvinism there. In German they are similarly called "W-Fragen", because the respective question words all start with 'w'.

Comment: I don't think I've heard any other term in linguistics but you could use "interrogative question" as a synonym.

Comment: As far as I know, wh-questions are _special questions_ while yes/no ones are _general questions_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“Content question” is common. I’ve seen that used in typologically oriented grammars of languages from all over the world.

I’ve also seen non-polarity question, though I like that option less.

Comment: Thanks, could you link to anything for both terms, like part of a Wikipedia page?

Answer (score 2):

Insofar as "yes-no" question has been replaced with "polar question", the alternative of ["non-polar"](http://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Edeutsch/Grammatik/WordOrder/Interrogatives.html) question seems most reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

In the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (which I think is considered the authoritative grammar to date) they’re called “open interrogatives” (yes-no questions are called “closed interrogatives”) and are one of the five
types of clauses in English.